# javac returning incorrect error code with annotation processor

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac

When you run javac with a annotation processor and a corrupted jar in your classpath java errors out but returns 0 as the error code(0 means it ran without any errors). If you run the same command without the annotation processor it returns 1 as the error code. So adding a annotationProcessor takes away the error code.

below is some example output:

```
 running compile with a corrupted jar
 error: error reading corruptedJar.jar; error in opening zip file
 Using Test AnnotationProcessor
 Error level 0
 running compile without the corrupted jar
 Using Test AnnotationProcessor
 Error level 0
 running compile without the annotationProcessor but with the corrupted jar
 error: error reading corruptedJar.jar; error in opening zip file
 1 error
 Error level 1
```

the bat file i used to run the above out put is

```
 @echo off
 echo running compile with a corrupted jar
 javac -cp annotationProcessor.jar;corruptedJar.jar HelloWorld.java
 echo Error level %errorlevel%
 echo running compile without the corrupted jar
 javac -cp annotationProcessor.jar HelloWorld.java
 echo Error level %errorlevel%
 echo running compile without the annotationProcessor but with the corrupted jar
 javac -cp corruptedJar.jar HelloWorld.java
 echo Error level %errorlevel%
```

Am I missing a parameter or is this a bug inside javac that is returning a incorrect error level?

edit..

source code for everything https://gist.github.com/ludjer/570708438dbcb3f08106

the annotationProcessor.jar has one class in it called AnnotationProcessor

the corruptedJar.jar is a corrupted zip file(technically could be any non zip file for the test mine was a text file with a renamed extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened a bug with oracle and it is on the JDK bug tracker:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151255

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have encountered this problem again.When I was building my application using Maven 3.6.3, I had two applications A and B that had a dependency relationship. B relied on A's jar. When I built both A and B simultaneously, A successfully built them. Although B threw an exception, Javac believed that B had built successfully. I unpacked the jar package that B typed and found that there was no class file inside. So I searched for the reason based on the exception information, and found that Javac was divided into multiple rounds when processing annotations. If an abort occurred in a certain round stage, Javac would not be able to find the delegate compiler. If Javac's own errors were 0 at this time, it would consider compilation successful, but the specific error information was reported to the global DiagnosticCollector by the delegate compiler, So even though Maven printed an error, it didn't stop working due to the error, but instead continued to package and ultimately printed an incorrect package.